# how to get foreign key constraints defined in a database?

Tags: postgresql

Database:  PostgreSQL 9.5.20 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.5.20-1.pgdg18.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

I need to return foreign key constraints defined in a database and I tried the below query but no results and I run it remotely by pgAdmin V.4

```
 select kcu.table_schema || '.' ||kcu.table_name as foreign_table,
   '>-' as rel,
   rel_tco.table_schema || '.' || rel_tco.table_name as primary_table,
   string_agg(kcu.column_name, ', ') as fk_columns,
   kcu.constraint_name
from information_schema.table_constraints tco
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
      on tco.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
      and tco.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
join information_schema.referential_constraints rco
      on tco.constraint_schema = rco.constraint_schema
      and tco.constraint_name = rco.constraint_name
join information_schema.table_constraints rel_tco
      on rco.unique_constraint_schema = rel_tco.constraint_schema
      and rco.unique_constraint_name = rel_tco.constraint_name
where tco.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
group by kcu.table_schema,
     kcu.table_name,
     rel_tco.table_name,
     rel_tco.table_schema,
     kcu.constraint_name
order by kcu.table_schema,
     kcu.table_name;
```

Comment: Your query seems to run just fine. Are you sure you have FK defined? What does select *
  from information_schema.table_constraints tco 
  where tco.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' ; return

Comment: it gives me empty

Comment: That means you don not have any FK defined.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, really you are right